# Import all fields (and subfields) of XML as dataframe

Tags: xml, r, import

To do some analysis I want to import a XML to a dataframe using R and the XML package. Example of XML file:

```
<watchers shop_name="TEST" created_at="September 14, 2012 05:44">
<watcher channel="Site Name">
    <code>123456</code>
    <search_key>TestKey</search_key>
    <date>September 14, 2012 04:15</date>
    <result>Found</result>
    <link>http://www.test.com/fakeurl</link>
    <price>100.0</price>
    <shipping>0.0</shipping>
    <origposition>0</origposition>
    <name>Name Test</name>
    <results>
        <result position="1">
            <c_name>CTest1</c_name>
            <c_price>599.49</c_price>
            <c_shipping>0.0</c_shipping>
            <c_total_price>599.49</c_total_price>
            <c_rating>8.3</c_rating>
            <c_delivery/>
        </result><result position="2">
            <c_name>CTest2</c_name>
            <c_price>654.0</c_price>
            <c_shipping>0.0</c_shipping>
            <c_total_price>654.0</c_total_price>
            <c_rating>9.8</c_rating>
            <c_delivery/>
        </result>
        <result position="3">
            <c_name>CTest3</c_name>
            <c_price>654.0</c_price>
            <c_shipping>0.0</c_shipping>
            <c_total_price>654.0</c_total_price>
            <c_rating>8.8</c_rating>
            <c_delivery/>
        </result>
    </results>
</watcher>
</watchers>
```

I want to have the rows of the dataframe containing the following fields:

```
shop_name   created_at  code    search_key  date    result
link    price   shipping    origposition    name    
position    c_name  c_price c_shipping  c_total_price   
c_rating    c_delivery
```

This means that the child nodes must be taken into account as well, which would result in a dataframe of three rows in this example (since the results show 3 positions). The fields

```
shop_name   created_at  code    search_key
date    result  link    price   shipping    
origposition    name
```

are the same for each of these rows.

I am able to go through the XML file, but I am unable to get a dataframe with the fields i want. When I convert the dataframe to a dataframe I get the following fields:

```
"code"       "search_key"      "date"     "result"  
"link" "price"      "shipping"   "origposition"  
"name"    "results"
```

Here the fields

```
shop_name   created_at
```

are missing at the beginning and the 'results' are put together in a String under the column "results".

It must be possible to get the wanted dataframe, but I do not know how to do this exactly.

**UPDATE**

The solution provided by @MvG works brilliantly on the test XML file stated above. However the column 'result' can also have the value "Not Found". Entries with this value will miss certain fields (always the same filed) and therefore yield a "number of columns of arguments do not match"-error when running the solution. I would like these entries to be put in the dataframe as well, with the fields that are not present left empty. I do not understand how to incorporate this scenario.

**test.xml**

```
<watchers shop_name="TEST" created_at="September 14, 2012 05:44">
<watcher channel="Site Name">
    <code>123456</code>
    <search_key>TestKey</search_key>
    <date>September 14, 2012 04:15</date>
    <result>Found</result>
    <link>http://www.test.com/fakeurl</link>
    <price>100.0</price>
    <shipping>0.0</shipping>
    <origposition>0</origposition>
    <name>Name Test</name>
    <results>
        <result position="1">
            <c_name>CTest1</c_name>
            <c_price>599.49</c_price>
            <c_shipping>0.0</c_shipping>
            <c_total_price>599.49</c_total_price>
            <c_rating>8.3</c_rating>
            <c_delivery/>
        </result><result position="2">
            <c_name>CTest2</c_name>
            <c_price>654.0</c_price>
            <c_shipping>0.0</c_shipping>
        <c_total_price>654.0</c_total_price>
        <c_rating>9.8</c_rating>
        <c_delivery/>
    </result>
    <result position="3">
        <c_name>CTest3</c_name>
        <c_price>654.0</c_price>
        <c_shipping>0.0</c_shipping>
        <c_total_price>654.0</c_total_price>
        <c_rating>8.8</c_rating>
        <c_delivery/>
    </result>
</results>
</watcher>
<watcher channel="Shopping">
    <code>12804</code>
    <search_key></search_key>
    <date></date>
    <result>Not found</result>
    <link>https://www.test.com/testing1323p</link>
    <price>0.0</price>
    <shipping>0.0</shipping>
    <origposition>0</origposition>
    <name>MOOVM6002020</name>
    <results>
    </results>
</watcher>
</watchers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more generic approach. Every node is classified as one of three cases:

- If the node name is of kind `rows`, then the data frames from child nodes will result in different rows of the result.
- If the node name is of kind `cols`, then the data frames from child nodes will result in different columns of the result.
- If the node name is of kind `value`, then a data frame with a single value will be constructed, using the node name as the column name and the node value as the column value.
- For all three cases, attributes of the node will be added to the data frame.

The call for your application is given towards the bottom.

```r
library(XML)

zeroColSingleRow <- function() {
  res <- data.frame(dummy=NA)
  res$dummy <- NULL
  stopifnot(nrow(res) == 1, ncol(res) == 0)
  return (res)
}

xml2df <- function(node, classifier) {
  if (! inherits(node, c("XMLInternalElementNode", "XMLElementNode"))) {
    return (zeroColSingleRow())
  }
  kind <- classifier(node)
  if (kind == "rows") {
    cdf <- lapply(xmlChildren(node), xml2df, classifier)
    if (length(cdf) == 0) {
      res <- zeroColSingleRow()
    }
    else {
      names <- unique(unlist(lapply(cdf, colnames)))
      cdf <- lapply(cdf, function(i) {
        missing <- setdiff(names, colnames(i))
        if (length(missing) > 0) {
          i[missing] <- NA
        }
        return (i)
      })
      res <- do.call(rbind, cdf)
    }
  }
  else if (kind == "cols") {
    cdf <- lapply(xmlChildren(node), xml2df, classifier)
    if (length(cdf) == 0) {
      res <- zeroColSingleRow()
    }
    else {
      res <- cdf[[1]]
      if (length(cdf) > 1) {
        for (i in 2:length(cdf)) {
          res <- merge(res, cdf[[i]], by=NULL)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    stopifnot(kind == "value")
    res <- data.frame(xmlValue(node))
    names(res) <- xmlName(node)
  }
  if (ncol(res) == 0) {
    res <- zeroColSingleRow()
  }
  attr <- xmlAttrs(node)
  if (length(attr) > 0) {
    attr <- do.call(data.frame, as.list(attr))
    res <- merge(attr, res, by=NULL)
  }
  rownames(res) <- NULL
  return(res)
}

doc<-xmlParse("test.xml")

xml2df(xmlRoot(doc), function(node) {
  name <- xmlName(node)
  if (name %in% c("watchers", "results"))
    return("rows")
  # make sure to treat results/result different from watcher/result
  if (name %in% c("watcher", "result") &&
      xmlName(xmlParent(node)) == paste0(name, "s"))
    return("cols")
  return("value")
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for XML testfile stated in the question. I get the following error now:  numbers of columns of arguments do not match. I also know where this error comes from. I have updated the question to show where this error comes from.

Comment: The Result (Found/Not found) field is also missing by the way!

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden, I've extended my code to deal with inhomogenous sets of columns, and with empty containers as well. This code is far from pretty, but it should get the job done. If anyone wants to improve on it, feel free to do so. Note that part of the problem came from the fact that `<result>` has different semantics in different places of the xml tree. That's the reason I now take a function to classify nodes.

Comment: The script now does exactly what I want! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possibility:

```r
attr2df <- function(n) do.call(data.frame, as.list(xmlAttrs(n)))
cbind(attr2df(xmlRoot(doc)), 
  do.call(rbind, xpathApply(doc, "//watcher", function(w) {
    x <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = list(w))
    x$results<-NULL
    cbind(attr2df(w), x,
          xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(w, "results/result")))
  } ))
)
```

Iterate over all watchers. For each watcher, read its subtree to data frame `x`, and read its result nodes to another data frame. Remove the results from the first data frame, then bind the columns of both together, and throw in the attributes from the watcher as well. This application will yield one data.frame per watcher, and the outer rbind cal will combine them to a single data frame. The outermost cbind will add the attributes of the root node.

The result will have these names:

```
 [1] "shop_name"     "created_at"    "channel"       "code"         
 [5] "search_key"    "date"          "result"        "link"         
 [9] "price"         "shipping"      "position"      "name"         
[13] "c_name"        "c_price"       "c_shipping"    "c_total_price"
[17] "c_rating"      "c_delivery"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand your explanation, but do not know exactly how to apply the function to the parsed XML    doc = xmlParse('test.xml'). I get 'ERROR:  
  arguments imply differing number of rows'

Comment: Also one of the position fields is missing (I noticed that in the XML there were 2 position variables. One general and when as child). I renamed the first one to origposition to avoid any duplicate column names.

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden, it works for me using R 2.15.1. I often cbind data frames where one has one row and the other multiple rows, perhaps that doesn't work in older versions of R.

Comment: I'm also using R 2.15.1, so that is not the problem. How do you exactly initiate the function? Do you also use  doc = xmlParse('test.xml') and then the function you gave? And how come there is one position field missing?

Comment: Yes, I'm loading the document as you do. As far as I can tell, `xmlToDataFrame` only parses child elements, not attributes, so the second `position` is simply lost since I don't pass that to `attr2df`.