# Scraping with rvest - complete with NAs when tag is not present

Tags: r, tags, web-scraping, rvest

I want to parse this HTML: and get this elements from it:

a) `p` tag, with `class: "normal_encontrado"`.
b) `div` with `class: "price"`.

Sometimes, the `p` tag is not present in some products. If this is the case, an `NA` should be added to the vector collecting the text from this nodes.

The idea is to have 2 vectors with the same length, and after join them to make a `data.frame`. Any ideas?

The HTML part:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="product_price" id="product_price_186251">
  <p class="normal_encontrado">
    S/. 2,799.00
  </p>

  <div id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_10461_div_10" class="price">
    S/. 2,299.00
  </div>    
</div>

<div class="product_price" id="product_price_232046">
  <div id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_10461_div_10" class="price">
    S/. 4,999.00
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

R Code:

```
library(rvest)

page_source <- read_html("r.html")

r.precio.antes <- page_source %>%
html_nodes(".normal_encontrado") %>%
html_text()

r.precio.actual <- page_source %>%
html_nodes(".price") %>%
html_text()
```

Comment: Something like this might be helpful - [R dataframe from xml when values are multiple or missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349630/r-dataframe-from-xml-when-values-are-multiple-or-missing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tag is not found, rvest returns a character(0). So assuming you will find at most one current and one regular price in each div.product_price, you can use this:

```
pacman::p_load("rvest", "dplyr")

get_prices <- function(node){
  r.precio.antes <- html_nodes(node, 'p.normal_encontrado') %>% html_text
  r.precio.actual <- html_nodes(node, 'div.price') %>% html_text

  data.frame(
    precio.antes = ifelse(length(r.precio.antes)==0, NA, r.precio.antes),
    precio.actual = ifelse(length(r.precio.actual)==0, NA, r.precio.actual), 
    stringsAsFactors=F
  )

}

doc <- read_html('test.html') %>% html_nodes("div.product_price")
lapply(doc, get_prices) %>%
  rbind_all
```

**Edited:** I misunderstood the input data, so changed the script to work with  just a single html page.

Comment: The more clear method, thanks. I also like Grothendick method, but I've never used the XML package.

Answer (score 4):

Using the XML package parse the input with `xmlTreeParse` and then use `xpathSApply` to interate over the `product_price` class `div` nodes.  For each such node the anonyous function gets the value of the `div` and `p` subnodes.  The resulting character matrix `m` is reworked into a data frame `DF` and the columns are cleaned removing any character that is not a dot or digit and also removing any dot followed by a non-digit.  Copnvert result to numeric. Note that no special processing for the missing `p` case is needed.

```
# input

Lines <- '<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="product_price" id="product_price_186251">
  <p class="normal_encontrado">
    S/. 2,799.00
  </p>

  <div id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_10461_div_10" class="price">
    S/. 2,299.00
  </div>    
</div>

<div class="product_price" id="product_price_232046">
  <div id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_10461_div_10" class="price">
    S/. 4,999.00
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'

# code to read input and produce a data.frame

library(XML)
doc <- xmlTreeParse(Lines, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

m <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class = 'product_price']", function(node) {
  list(p = xmlValue(node[["p"]]), div = xmlValue(node[["div"]])) })

DF <- as.data.frame(t(m), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # rework into data frame
DF[] <- lapply(DF, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^.0-9]|[.]\\D", "", x))) # clean
```

The result is:

```
> DF
     p  div
1 2799 2299
2   NA 4999
```

Answer (score 3):

Go one level up from your target and `lapply` over each parent element:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html('<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="product_price" id="product_price_186251">
  <p class="normal_encontrado">
    S/. 2,799.00
  </p>

  <div id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_10461_div_10" class="price">
    S/. 2,299.00
  </div>    
</div>

<div class="product_price" id="product_price_232046">
  <div id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_10461_div_10" class="price">
    S/. 4,999.00
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>')

prod <- html_nodes(pg, "div.product_price")
do.call(rbind, lapply(prod, function(x) {
  norm <- tryCatch(xml_text(xml_node(x, "p.normal_encontrado")),
                   error=function(err) {NA})
  price <- tryCatch(xml_text(xml_node(x, "div.price")),
                    error=function(err) {NA})
  data.frame(norm, price, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}))

##                     norm                  price
## 1 \n    S/. 2,799.00\n   \n    S/. 2,299.00\n  
## 2                   <NA> \n    S/. 4,999.00\n
```

I have no idea if you wanted the strings trimmed or anything else done, but those machinations are pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most idiomatic way to do this, but you can use lapply over the `.product_price` nodes like this:

```
r.precio.antes <- page_source %>% html_nodes(".product_price") %>%
  lapply(. %>% html_nodes(".normal_encontrado") %>% html_text() %>% 
     ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .)) %>% unlist
```

This will return NA whenever the `.normal_encontrado` element is not found.

```
r.precio.antes
# [1] "\n                    S/. 2,799.00\n                "
# [2] NA  

length(r.precio.antes) # 2
```

If I wanted to develop the code to make it clearer, first I isolate the `.product_price` nodes:

```
product_nodes <- page_source %>% html_nodes(".product_price")
```

Then I could use `lapply` in more traditional way:

```
r.precio.antes <- lapply(product_nodes, function(pn) {
  pn %>% html_nodes(".normal_encontrado") %>% html_text()
})
r.precio.antes <- unlist(r.precio.antes)
```

Instead I'm using the `magrittr` syntax for `lapply`, see e.g. the [end of the Functional sequences paragraph here](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/12/01/magrittr-1-5/#functional-sequences).

One final hurdle is that if the element is not found, this will return `character(0)` rather than `NA` like you wanted. So I'm adding `ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .))` to the pipe inside the lapply to fix that.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the code? Especially  this part: `lapply(. %>% html_nodes(".normal_encontrado")` why is the "." there (after lapply)? And also: `(function(x) ifelse(identical(x, character(0)), NA, x)) )`. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I realized you could just do `ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .))` instead of the `(function(x) ...)` syntax. I've developed the code and explanations. Is this clearer?