# Using rvest html_nodes() to store li elements for each item scraped

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to download some data, for example I can use the following:

```
  "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/sagrada-familia/l/19/" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-CardFeatures-wrapper")
```

With the following strucutre:

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ node:<externalptr> 
  ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ node:<externalptr> 
  ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_nodeset"
```

This corresponds to two properties from the website.

I am interested in extracting the items "li" from the lists

```
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/sagrada-familia/l/19/" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-CardFeatures-wrapper") %>% 
  html_nodes("li")
```

Which gives:

```
{xml_nodeset (10)}
 [1] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">2 habs.</li>\n
 [2] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">1 baño</li>\n
 [3] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">60 m²</li>\n
 [4] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">3ª Planta</li>\n
 [5] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">Balcón</li>
 [6] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">3 habs.</li>\n
 [7] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">1 baño</li>\n
 [8] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">75 m²</li>\n
 [9] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">5ª Planta</li>\n
[10] <li class="re-CardFeatures-feature">Ascensor</li>
```

However, now, it has broken the "2 list" strucutre that I originally had (one for each property).

My question is, how can I extract the `html_nodes()` for the two properties but store them as they correspond to each given property?

i.e. the list should "break" after "3 hab" since this is the first item of the second property.

Comment: See this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673908/how-do-you-scrape-items-together-so-you-dont-lose-the-index/56675147#56675147

Answer (score 1):

To get the "2 list" we can use `lapply` as follows,

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
house = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/sagrada-familia/l/19/" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(".re-CardFeatures-wrapper") 


lis = lapply(house, function(x) x %>% html_nodes("li"))
```

Now we have `lis` with info of each property stored in different element of a list.