# How to report NA when scraping a web with R and it does not have value?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping from a page in booking.com and creating the dataframe I have noticed that not all hotels have ratings.

I tried this for example:

```
# Got the elements from Inspect code of the page
titles_page <- page %>% html_elements("div[data-testid='title'][class='fcab3ed991 a23c043802']") %>% html_text()
prices_page <- page %>% html_elements("span[data-testid='price-and-discounted-price']") %>% html_text()
ratings_page <- page %>% html_elements("div[aria-label^='Punteggio di']") %>% html_text()

# The variable ratings
tryCatch(expr ={
      ratings_page <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", value = "div[aria-label^='Punteggio di']")$getElementAttribute('value')
    },   
    #If the information does not exist in this way it writes NA to the ratings element
    error = function(e){          
      ratings_page <-NA
    })
```

And it does not change anything.

How to report NA where the object does not have value?

[The link](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fsearchresults.it.html%3Fss%3DFirenze%252C%2BToscana%252C%2BItalia%26efdco%3D1%26label%3Dbooking-name-L*Xf2U1sq4*GEkIwcLOALQS267777916051%253Apl%253Ata%253Ap1%253Ap22%252C563%252C000%253Aac%253Aap%253Aneg%253Afi%253Atikwd-65526620%253Alp9069992%253Ali%253Adec%253Adm%253Appccp%26aid%3D376363%26lang%3Dit%26sb%3D1%26src_elem%3Dsb%26src%3Dindex%26dest_id%3D-117543%26dest_type%3Dcity%26ac_position%3D0%26ac_click_type%3Db%26ac_langcode%3Dit%26ac_suggestion_list_length%3D5%26search_selected%3Dtrue%26search_pageview_id%3D2e375b14ad810329%26ac_meta%3DGhAyZTM3NWIxNGFkODEwMzI5IAAoATICaXQ6BGZpcmVAAEoAUAA%253D%26checkin%3D2023-06-11%26checkout%3D2023-06-18%26group_adults%3D2%26no_rooms%3D1%26group_children%3D0%26sb_travel_purpose%3Dleisure%26fbclid%3DIwAR1BGskP8uicO9nlm5aW7U1A9eABbSwhMNNeQ0gQ-PNoRkHP859L7u0fIsE&h=AT1orO0rFoHaMP5P5GZKi6Ff_-qXlZ2FP8zgoCbD1n8SIGgzx0gmJuIzo3WrOG9wChhX755yQPsA-tvIZ55oK6AwCxnYvSoFXmzFsvxp5F03fLimvwltLSg-W3lsOsei0fAa9W6R40s)

Comment: Tried the solution but it does not happen anything. take a look:

```#parse out the parent node for each parent

  titles_page <- page %>% html_elements("div[data-testid='title']") %>% html_children()
  
  #parse out the requested information from each child.

  prices_page <- titles_page %>% html_elements("span[data-testid='price-and-discounted-price']") %>% html_text()

  ratings_page <- titles_page %>% html_elements("div[aria-label^='Punteggio di']") %>% html_text()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the strategy from this link: [How do you scrape items together so you don't lose the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673908/how-do-you-scrape-items-together-so-you-dont-lose-the-index/56675147#56675147).

The key here is using `html_element()` (without the s).  `html_element()` will always return an answer even if it is NA.  This way if the element is missing in the parent node, NA will fill the gaps.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

#read the page
url <-"https://www.booking.com/searchresults.it.html?ss=Firenze%2C+Toscana%2C+Italia&efdco=1&label=booking-name-L*Xf2U1sq4*GEkIwcLOALQS267777916051%3Apl%3Ata%3Ap1%3Ap22%2C563%2C000%3Aac%3Aap%3Aneg%3Afi%3Atikwd-65526620%3Alp9069992%3Ali%3Adec%3Adm%3Appccp&aid=376363&lang=it&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=index&dest_id=-117543&dest_type=city&ac_position=0&ac_click_type=b&ac_langcode=it&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=2e375b14ad810329&ac_meta=GhAyZTM3NWIxNGFkODEwMzI5IAAoATICaXQ6BGZpcmVAAEoAUAA%3D&checkin=2023-06-11&checkout=2023-06-18&group_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure&fbclid=IwAR1BGskP8uicO9nlm5aW7U1A9eABbSwhMNNeQ0gQ-PNoRkHP859L7u0fIsE"
page <- read_html(url)

#parse out the parent node for each parent 
properties <- html_elements(page, xpath=".//div[@data-testid='property-card']")

#now find the information from each parent
#notice html_element - no "s"
title <- properties %>% html_element("div[data-testid='title']") %>% html_text()
prices <- properties %>% html_element("span[data-testid='price-and-discounted-price']") %>% html_text()    
ratings <- properties %>% html_element(xpath=".//div[@aria-label]") %>% html_text()

data.frame(title, prices, ratings)

                                       title   prices ratings
1                   Sweetly home in Florence US$1.918    <NA>
2                                   Pepi Red US$3.062        
3                 hu Firenze Camping in Town   US$902     8,4
4                              Plus Florence US$1.754     7,9
5                     Artemente Florence B&B US$4.276        
6                                Villa Aruch US$1.658        
7                                Hotel Berna US$2.184        
8                                Hotel Gioia US$2.437        
9                              Hotel Magenta US$3.250        
10                              Villa Neroli US$3.242        
11                       Residenza Florentia US$2.792     8,0
12                Ridolfi Sei Suite Florence US$1.243    <NA>
...
```

Comment: Gonna test it right away.

Comment: I get this 
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"xml_nodeset"’ to a data.frame

Comment: The above code works on my system with the sample URL.  Double check (with `str()` function) to make sure title, prices, ratings, etc. have all been converted from a node into a character string using the `html_text()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following. Untested.

```
# The variable ratings
ratings_page <- tryCatch(
  expr = {
    elem <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", value = "div[aria-label^='Punteggio di']")
    elem$getElementAttribute('value')
  },   
  # If the information does not exist in this way it writes NA to the ratings element
  error = function(e) NA
)
```

Comment: This was a superb anwer, but when I ran the code, I got a dataframe with all NA values. I guess it misses only sth small

Comment: @Anisa We don't have an url to test the code. Furthermore, you are using RSelenium, not rvest.

Comment: No I’m using Rvest, I’ve not loaded Rselenium

Comment: @Anisa But `remDr$findElements` and `elem$getElementAttribute` are both RSelenium code. Maybe the error comes from there, try to run the first of these instructions to see what you get. Probably a *"could not find function"* error. If I'm right, then the `expr` part of `tryCatch` will always give an error and the `error` part is always executed, always returning `NA`.

Comment: @Anisa Also, can you post the exact url in the question, please, so that we can test the code?

Comment: Ofc but it’s too long for comment. How can I send it otherwise?

Comment: @Anisa You can [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76029792/edit) and post the long url there. You must include a reason why the edit. Then save the edit.

Comment: I did it, check it