# Importing XML data to R with missing values

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I'm currently struggling to import data from an XML file into R.

The XML file has multiple records which i want on a single row of a dataframe. Example record:

```
<rec resultID="5">
  <header shortDbName="psyh" longDbName="PsycINFO" uiTerm="2015-99210-426">
    <controlInfo>
      <bkinfo>
        <btl>The impact of zoo live animal presentations on students' propensity to engage in conservation behaviors.</btl>
        <aug />
        <isbn>9781321491562</isbn>
      </bkinfo>
      <chapinfo />
      <revinfo />
      <dissinfo>
        <disstl>The impact of zoo live animal presentations on students' propensity to engage in conservation behaviors.</disstl>
      </dissinfo>
      <jinfo>
        <jtl>Dissertation Abstracts International Section A: Humanities and Social Sciences</jtl>
        <issn type="Print">04194209</issn>
      </jinfo>
      <pubinfo>
        <dt year="2015" month="01" day="01">20150101</dt>
        <vid>76</vid>
        <iid>5-A(E)</iid>
      </pubinfo>
      <artinfo>
        <ui type="umi">AAI3671924</ui>
        <tig>
          <atl>The impact of zoo live animal presentations on students' propensity to engage in conservation behaviors.</atl>
        </tig>
        <aug>
          <au>Kirchgessner, Mandy L.</au>
        </aug>
        <sug>
          <subj type="major">Animals</subj>
          <subj type="major">Hope</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Conservation (Ecological Behavior)</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Outreach Programs</subj>
          <subj type="minor">Psychological Development</subj>
        </sug>
        <ab>Zoos frequently deploy outreach programs, often called "Zoomobiles," to schools; these programs incorporate zoo resources, such as natural artifacts and live animals, in order to teach standardized content and in hopes of inspiring students to protect the environment. Educational research at zoos is relatively rare, and research on their outreach programs is non-existent. This leaves zoos vulnerable to criticisms as they have little to no evidence that their strategies support their missions, which target conservation outcomes. This study seeks to shed light on this gap by analyzing the impact that live animals have on offsite program participants' interests in animals and subsequent conservation outcomes. The theoretical lens is derived from the field of Conservation Psychology, which believes personal connections with nature serve as the motivational component to engagement with conservation efforts. Using pre, post, and delayed surveys combined with Zoomobile presentation observations, I analyzed the roles of sensory experiences in students' (N=197) development of animal interest and conservation behaviors. Results suggest that touching even one animal during presentations has a significant impact on conservation intents and sustainment of those intents. Although results on interest outcomes are conflicting, this study points to ways this kind of research can make significant contributions to zoo learning outcomes. Other significant variables, such as emotional predispositions and animal-related excitement, are discussed in light of future research directions. (PsycINFO Database Record (c) 2015 APA, all rights reserved)</ab>
        <pubtype>Dissertation Abstract</pubtype>
        <doctype>Dissertation</doctype>
      </artinfo>
      <language>English</language>
    </controlInfo>
    <displayInfo>
      <pLink>
        <url>http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=psyh&amp;AN=2015-99210-426&amp;site=ehost-live&amp;scope=site</url>
      </pLink>
    </displayInfo>
  </header>
</rec>
```

I tried the following but it gets way to slow with larger datasets. Also, when there is missing data from a node, i'd like the function to return "NA" for the given row/record however i dont think this can be done with this function?

```
title <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(xmltop, "//atl"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
author <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(xmltop, "//artinfo/aug/au[1]"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
abstract <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(xmltop, "//artinfo/ab[1]"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
year <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(xmltop, "//pubinfo/dt"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried to follow the instructions here [R dataframe from XML when values are multiple or missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349630/r-dataframe-from-xml-when-values-are-multiple-or-missing) with no success:

```
doc = xmlParse(file.choose(), useInternalNodes = TRUE)

do.call(rbind, xpathApply(xmltop, "/rec", function(node) {
  auth <- xmlValue(node[["artinfo/aug/au[1]"]])
    if (is.null(auth)) auth <- NA
  year <- xmlValue(node[["//pubinfo/dt"]])
    if (is.null(year)) year <- NA
  title <- xmlValue(node[["//atl"]])
    if (is.null(title)) title <- NA
  abstract <- xmlValue(node[["//artinfo/ab[1]"]])
    if (is.null(abstract)) abstract <- NA

  data.frame(auth, year, title, abstract, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

}))
```

I'm still not very acquitanted with XPath and R but i'd guess there's some sort of issue with the "node" bit above?

Comment: Do you have a general purpose language (C#, Java, Perl, PHP, Python, even VBA with MS Excel/Access) installed with R? These languages can run XSLT which can redesign your XML to a simpler format for an R import with `xmlToDataFrame()`?

Comment: xmtodataframeframe works (i used it above). I do have VBA/Python. I tried importing using excel however this used multiple rows per /rec node wheras i only want one row per node.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, consider running XSLT to simplify your XML into a one-child level of row and columns which can then be easily imported into R using `xmlToDataFrame()`:

```
<row>
  <column>data</column>
  <column>data</column>
  <column>data</column>
<row>
<row>
  <column>data</column>
  <column>data</column>
  <column>data</column>
<row>
```

R has yet to have a universal XSLT 1.0 processor. Fortunately, most general purpose languages including C#, Java, Python, PHP, Perl, VB, can run XSLT scripts to re-format/re-design complex XML data. Below are Python and VBA scripts with the final R import line.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl or .xslt file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Removes Element/Keeps Children Data -->
  <xsl:template match="rec">    
      <xsl:apply-templates />    
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replaces Element/Keeps Children Data -->
  <xsl:template match="rec">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Extracts Needed Elements -->
  <xsl:template match="controlInfo">
    <row>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="artinfo/tig/atl"/></title>
      <author><xsl:value-of select="artinfo/aug/au"/></author>
      <abstract><xsl:value-of select="artinfo/ab"/></abstract>
      <year><xsl:value-of select="pubinfo/dt"/></year>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>

 <!-- Removes Element (empty template) --> 
 <xsl:template match="displayInfo"/> 

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script *(using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module)*

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml'))
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl'))

# TRANSFORMS INPUT
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# OUTPUTS FILE
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True,  xml_declaration=True)
print(tree_out.decode("utf-8"))

xmlfile = open('Output.xml','wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**VBA Macro** *(using [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object)*

```
Sub TransformXML()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object
    Dim strPath As String, xslFile As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' INITIALIZE MSXML OBJECTS '
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL '
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML '
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

    ' OUTPUT XML '
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set newDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

**XML** Transformed Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <data>
      <row>
        <title>The impact of zoo live animal presentations on students' 
               propensity to engage in conservation behaviors.</title>
        <author>Kirchgessner, Mandy L.</author>
        <abstract>Zoos frequently deploy outreach programs, often called 
                  "Zoomobiles," to schools; these programs incorporate zoo resources, such as 
                  natural artifacts and live animals, in order to teach standardized content 
                  and in hopes of inspiring students to protect the environment. Educational 
                  research at zoos is relatively rare, and research on their outreach programs 
                  is non-existent. This leaves zoos vulnerable to criticisms as they have 
                  little to no evidence that their strategies support their missions, which 
                  target conservation outcomes. This study seeks to shed light on this gap by 
                  analyzing the impact that live animals have on offsite program participants' 
                  interests in animals and subsequent conservation outcomes. The theoretical 
                  lens is derived from the field of Conservation Psychology, which believes 
                  personal connections with nature serve as the motivational component to 
                  engagement with conservation efforts. Using pre, post, and delayed surveys 
                  combined with Zoomobile presentation observations, I analyzed the roles of 
                  sensory experiences in students' (N=197) development of animal interest and 
                  conservation behaviors. Results suggest that touching even one animal during 
                  presentations has a significant impact on conservation intents and 
                  sustainment of those intents. Although results on interest outcomes are 
                  conflicting, this study points to ways this kind of research can make 
                  significant contributions to zoo learning outcomes. Other significant 
                  variables, such as emotional predispositions and animal-related excitement, 
                  are discussed in light of future research directions. (PsycINFO Database 
                  Record (c) 2015 APA, all rights reserved)</abstract>
        <year>20150101</year>
      </row>
   </data>
```

**R** Script *(using XML package)*

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlToDataFrame("Output.xml")               # MISSING NODES RENDERS AS EMPTY
```