# Converting XML to dataframe when values are missing

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, missing-data

I read the similar question in this post here ([R dataframe from XML when values are multiple or missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349630/r-dataframe-from-xml-when-values-are-multiple-or-missing)
) but the format of the XML file is different than that of what I have. My XML is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <row 
     Id="-1" 
     Body="Hello! I am a programmer!" 
     OwnerUserId="11111" 
  />
<\users>
```

**First** of all, is this a correct XML or different kind?

**Second**, I have tried all of the answers in that post and none works for this XML format.

**Third**, In this case, if some of the rows don't have for example `OwnerUserId`, how can I parse those rows efficiently?

I have written the following code to do that and I am wondering if there is an efficient and faster way of doing that instead of reading rows by rows?

```
    posts <- xmlParse('path_to_file.xml')
    xml_posts <- xmlToList(posts)

    df_posts <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3))
    df_posts <- df_posts[-1,]
    colnames(df_posts) <- c(
        "Id"
      , "Text"
      , "User_ID"
                     )

    for(i in 1:length(xml_posts)){
        user_id <- 'none'
        xml_unlisted <- unlist(xml_posts[i])
        name <- names(xml_unlisted)

        if (length(xml_unlisted[name == "row.OwnerUserId"]) != 0){
            user_id <- xml_unlisted[name == "row.OwnerUserId"] 
        }

        df_temp <-  data.frame(list(
           xml_unlisted[name == "row.Id"]
          ,xml_unlisted[name == "row.Body"]
          ,user_id
            ))

        colnames(df_temp) <- c(
            "Id"
          , "Text"
          , "User_ID"
          )


        df_posts <- rbind(df_posts, df_temp)
    }

    head(df_posts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse xml, I would now use `xml2`. Assuming your xml as this form for multiple users, I would do this and get `NA` if an attribute is node present in the xml.

```r
xml_string <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <row 
     Id="1" 
     Body="Hello! I am a programmer!" 
     OwnerUserId="11111" 
  />
  <row 
     Id="2" 
     Body="Hello! I am a teacher!" 
  />
</users>'
library(xml2)
# for the pipe
library(magrittr)
# get the row nodes
xml <- read_xml(xml_string) %>% xml_find_all("row")
data.frame(
  Id = xml %>% xml_attr("Id"),
  Text = xml %>% xml_attr("Body"),
  User_ID = xml %>% xml_attr("OwnerUserId")
)
#>   Id                      Text User_ID
#> 1  1 Hello! I am a programmer!   11111
#> 2  2    Hello! I am a teacher!    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)
This library is much more efficient and it saves a lot of time.